# "Squeezing in" between polynomial and exponential

Tags: real-analysis, computational-complexity

Let $\mathbb{R}_+$ denote the set of positive reals. Let $\mathbb{R}_+^{\mathbb{R}_+}$  denote the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}_+$. For $f,g: \mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}_+$ we say $f\leq^* g$ if there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\geq N$.

Let $A=\{ f\in\mathbb{R}_+^{\mathbb{R}_+}: \exists n\in\mathbb{N}: f(x) = x^n \text{ for all x}\in \mathbb{R}_+\}$ and let $B=\{ f\in\mathbb{R}_+^{\mathbb{R}_+}: \exists \varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_+: f(x) = (1+\varepsilon)^x \text{ for all x}\in \mathbb{R}_+\}$.

**Question.** Is there $s\in\mathbb{R}_+^{\mathbb{R}_+}$ such that for all $a\in A$ and for all $b\in B$ we have $a\leq^* s\leq^* b$?

**Soft question.** (Just out of interest; not needed for acceptance of answer.) If "yes" to the main question above, is there a "natural" problem that is not polynomial, but solvable in "time $s$"?

Comment: To answer your second question: most NP-complete problems have subexponential algorithms, but they are all conjectured to have no polynomial time algorithms.

Comment: @Wojowu, are you sure about NP *complete* problems having subexponential algorithms? (If one of them does, wouldn't they all?)

Comment: @BarryCipra In mind I had [this definition of subexponential time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Second_definition) (matching the definition in Dominic's question), for that see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/are-there-subexponential-time-algorithms-for-np-complete-problems). This class is not closed under polynomial-time reductions, since if $f(n)$ is subexponential, $f(n^2)$ needn't be.

Comment: @Wojowu, thanks for the clarification/explanation.